# Treating iterable and not-iterable objects seamlessy

Tags: python, iterator

How can I make this function to work correctly independently from the iterability of the argument X and **without any if/else condition**?

I'd imagine this question was asked/answered before but I couldn't find anything.

```
def do_something(X):
  return map(lambda x: x ,X)

# Possible input:

do_something([1,2,3]) #-> [1,2,3]
do_something(1) # -> [1]
```

**EDIT**:

I expect the scalar argument to be treated as a 1D, one element array e.g. 1 -> [1], hence the return value should be always a list.

**Numpy Solution:**

Just realized that numpy provides this functionality:

```
import numpy

def do_something(X):
  return map(lambda x: x ,numpy.atleast_1d(X))
```

So now the question is: "Is there a way to achieve the same without importing numpy"?

Comment: What do you expect do happen in each case? Should the second version return the processed item directly, or a single-element list, for example? I assume that you're planning something other than the NOOP you're currently `map`ping?

Comment: I added the answer to the original question

Comment: be careful if you deal with strings.  they are iterable too (even 1 character strings)

Comment: `np.atleast_1d` is Python code with a couple of if/else blocks.

Comment: @memecs:  Have the answers below fully answered your question? If they have not you can edit your question to clarify why they haven't and include any missing information.

Answer (score 2):

[EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp).

```
def do_something(X):
    try:
       return map(lambda x: x, X)
    except TypeError:
       return map(lambda x: x, [X])
```

Basically, you try the `map` with the given `X` and if it fails, you try again with a single-element list containing `X`.

Note that if your function can raise `TypeError`, you'll need to check somehow whether the error is being raised by `map` or by the function it's calling. This is possible... with an `if` statement.

Comment: You were too quick for me. (I just copy and pasted the original code...)

Comment: It will do what you expect; strings are iterable, so you will end up with a list of characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the passed items is iterable or not, based on that you can handle it:

```
>>> from collections import Iterable
def do_something(X):
    f = lambda x: x**2
    if isinstance(X, Iterable):
        return map(f, X)
    return f(X)
>>> do_something([1, 2, 3, 4])
[1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> do_something(2)
4
>>> do_something(iter(range(3, 7)))
[9, 16, 25, 36]
```

If you wanted to return `[4]` in second case, then you need to modify it to:

```
def do_something(X):
    return map(lambda x: x**2, X if isinstance(X, Iterable) else [X])
```

Comment: No if-else i.e. no type checking ;)

Comment: @memecs why not? If these are conditions imposed as part of your homework, shouldn't you be doing this yourself?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why should this be an homework? I asked a simple question with a catch: no if-else. Why? Because that's additional lines which I don't want to type. Makes the code less elegant. From the current answers I understand there is no trivial solution to it (e.g. itertools providing some ad-hoc functions)

Comment: @memecs then that's information worth including in the question.

Comment: @memecs:  I feel you are being constrained by mistaken sense of elegance.

Answer (score 1):

I advise hiding the stuff you don't want to see in a helper function:

```
from collections import Iterable

def make_sure_iterable(X):
    return X if isinstance(X, Iterable) and not isinstance(X, basestring) else [X]
```

Then when you use the argument wrap it with a call to the helper function:

```
def do_something(X):
    return map(lambda x: x, make_sure_iterable(X))
```

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best option. Seems like a useful feature though to have available in itertools.